# How do I assure that a site that I visit does not know I have been there before?

Tags: authentication, web-browser, ip, fingerprinting, same-site-cookies

If I use the same machine (my PC) but with a different IP address and a different browser that I have never used to visit a site, will that site still be able to identify me? I don't understand the browser fingerprinting thing that well. To clarify, suppose I have visited a website with Chrome but later I visit that same site with Firefox on the same computer but a different IP address...will both visits be logged as the same person visiting them?

Comment: Wow I read it but I am not technical enough to follow it. Any way to simplify what I need to do to not be recognized as the same person visiting a site? I only need the site to know that I am not a previous visitor.

Comment: If the site is using particularly sophisticated methods (Google's ReCaptcha may be able to do this, as can certain ad companies), they may be able to infer who is visiting it. But if you're just trying to make a sockpuppet on a forum or something, it's very unlikely that it'll know it's the same person.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am not doing sockpuppets -- I am actually just trying to delete my previous history/affiliation with a site and get a clean slate as a new user. Let me give a more specific scenario -- I visited a site that decided to limit my activity in that I can no longer submit proposals because they think I have a duplicate account (I don't). I am certain they have flagged my IP and who knows what else. I want to just start all over with a new IP, new browser, new account, same machine. Will it work? I'm not up to no good :)

Comment: Ah. Then most likely they will not notice.

Comment: Thank you for the help and quick answers! I'll try it.

Comment: One more follow up related to this question. Earlier when I tried to create a new account on a different machine but same IP, the site allowed me to sign up but automatically put me in limited status (which clearly indicated flagged status). The only way they knew it was me was by IP, right? Or is there some other identifier?

Comment: @SamBranner what kind of data do you need to provide to create the account?

Comment: @Limit I couldn't add to the comments but to answer your question -- I just have to provide an email address- but I used a different one. So no other data was given. So it must be just the IP address they are using? And perhaps storing it somewhere in their site to identify me each time?